# Minimax going in order(Tic Tac Toe)

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to make use of the Minimax Algorithm and create a "Unbeatable Computer Player". I'm banging my head with this one for hours now and I cant seem to figure out why the "Computer" is going in order and not making the right decisions. Does anybody have an idea? maybe something sticks out for you I can't put my finger on what's wrong honestly. I bet it has something to do with the recursive call but I'm lost here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char BOARD[9][4];

void createBoard(){
    for(int i = 0;i < 9;i++){
        strcpy(BOARD[i], "[]");
    }
    strcpy(BOARD[6], "[X]");
    strcpy(BOARD[1], "[O]");
    strcpy(BOARD[3], "[X]");
}



void printBoard(){
    printf("\n\n");
    for(int i = 0;i < 9;i++){
        printf("%s", BOARD[i]);
        if((i + 1) % 3 == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}




void makeMove(char* player, int position){
    char playerFinal[5];
    strcpy(playerFinal, "[");
    strcat(playerFinal, player);
    strcat(playerFinal, "]");
    if(strcmp(BOARD[position], "[]") == 0){
        strcpy(BOARD[position], playerFinal);
    }
}





bool movesLeft(){
    for(int i = 0;i < 9;i++){
        if(strcmp(BOARD[i], "[]") == 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}





char* isWinner(){
    for(int i = 0;i < 9;i = i + 3){
        if(strcmp(BOARD[i], BOARD[i + 1]) == 0 && strcmp(BOARD[i + 1], BOARD[i + 2]) == 0){
            if(strcmp(BOARD[i], "[X]") == 0){
                return "X";
            }
            else if(strcmp(BOARD[i], "[O]") == 0){
                return "O";
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++){
        if(strcmp(BOARD[i], BOARD[i + 3]) == 0 && strcmp(BOARD[i + 3], BOARD[i + 6]) == 0){
            if(strcmp(BOARD[i], "[X]") == 0){
                return "X";
            }
            else if(strcmp(BOARD[i], "[O]") == 0){
                return "O";
            }
        }
    }
    if(strcmp(BOARD[0], BOARD[4]) == 0 && strcmp(BOARD[4], BOARD[8]) == 0){
        if(strcmp(BOARD[0], "[X]") == 0){
            return "X";
        }
        else if(strcmp(BOARD[0], "[O]") == 0){
            return "O";
        }
    }

    if(strcmp(BOARD[2], BOARD[4]) == 0 && strcmp(BOARD[4], BOARD[6]) == 0){
        if(strcmp(BOARD[2], "[X]") == 0){
            return "X";
        }
        else if(strcmp(BOARD[2], "[O]") == 0){
            return "O";
        }
    }
    if(!movesLeft()){
        return "tie";
    }
    return "";
}




int minimax(bool isMaximizing){
    char* winner = isWinner();
    printf("Function Called\n");
    printf("%s", winner);
    if(strcmp(winner, "O") == 0){
        return 10;
    }
    if(strcmp(winner, "X") == 0){
        return -10;
    }
    if(strcmp(winner, "tie") == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(isMaximizing){
        int score;
        int bestScore = -1000000;
        for(int i = 0;i < 9;i++){
            if(strcmp(BOARD[i], "[]") == 0){
                makeMove("O", i);
                score = minimax(false);
                strcpy(BOARD[i], "[]");
                if(score > bestScore){
                    bestScore = score;
                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
    else{
        int score;
        int bestScore = 1000000;
        for(int i = 0;i < 9;i++){
            if(strcmp(BOARD[i], "[]") == 0){
                makeMove("X", i);
                score = minimax(true);
                strcpy(BOARD[i], "[]");
                if(score < bestScore){
                    bestScore = score;
                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
}




void bestMove(){
    int bestScore = -1000;
    int position;
    for(int i = 0;i < 9;i++){
        if(strcmp(BOARD[i], "[]") == 0){
            int score;
            makeMove("O", i);
            score = minimax(false);
            strcpy(BOARD[i], "[]");
            printf("Position %d\n", i);
            printf("Best Score %d\n", bestScore);
            printf("Score %d\n", score);
            if(score > bestScore){
                bestScore = score;
                position = i;
            }
        }
    }
    makeMove("O", position);
}




int main(){
    int position;
    createBoard();
    printBoard();
    bool player = true;
    char* winner = "";
    while(strcmp(winner, "") == 0){
        if(player){
            printf("Its the Players Turn\nChoose a Position: ");
            scanf("%d", &position);
            makeMove("X", position -1);
            player = false;
            winner = isWinner();
        }
        else{
            printf("Its the Computers Turn");
            bestMove();
            player = true;
            winner = isWinner();
            }
        printBoard();
    }
    printf("The Winner is: %s\n", winner);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is "not making the right decisions"?

Comment: The "Computer" its not blocking X from winning if X for example, has two in a row the Computer doesnt block it instead its going in order from left to right

Comment: The computer is depressed because you made it start in a guaranteed-to-lose position (best score -10) and none of the possible moves changes that. Try it with an empty board instead.